# Kernel panic while booting Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, kernel, 23.04, btrfs, busybox

When I try to boot into Ubuntu 23.04 it gets me into an initramfs shell as shown in the below picture.

[image: BusyBox]

Running btrfs check gives no error for that partition.

When I exit this shell I see the real root of issue which is a kernel panic as shown in this picture.

[image: kernel panic]

Entering recovery mode gives no help as I find the same issue there, and no minimal GUI which gives several options.

Comment: Use your "Ubuntu Install media" in "Try Ubuntu"-mode, from there mount `/` on the disk you're attempting to boot above, then check the files in `/var/log/` to see if there are any real traces for / to the problem *(if `/` was possible to find in any boot attempts)*. The above is likely to be a consequence rather than any cause. The real problem cannot be pinpointed from the above.